# Get pointer to llvm::Value previously allocated for CreateLoad function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to llvm and I'm writing a small llvm IR Builder.
I use the IRBuilder and all these Create* functions to generate my IR.
What I'm trying to do is to create a **load** instruction which create a new SSA local variable with value of a previously allocated **llvm::Value**.

What I expected to have :

```
%2 = load i32* %1
```

With **%2** results of load instruction and **%1** my previously allocated Value (CreateAlloca)

Here is what I tried :

```
// Get Ptr from Val
Value* ptr = ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr((Constant*)loc[n],PointerType::getUnqual(builder->getInt32Ty()));

// Générate load instruction with the new Ptr
builder->CreateLoad(ptr);
```

And here is what I have :

```
%2 = load i32* null
```

**loc** is an array which contains all my llvm::Value*

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Or maybe if I'm on a bad way ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr()` creates a [constant expression](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions). So in effect, what you're trying to generate is equivalent to this IR:

```
%2 = load i32* inttoptr (i32 %1 to i32*)
```

But this is illegal since a constant expression, as hinted by its name, only supports [constants](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constants), and %1 isn't a constant. `ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr()` requires a `Constant` as a first argument to verify it, but you passed it a non-constant value which was forcefully cast to a constant.

The correct way to convert a non-constant integer to a pointer is with `IRBuilder::createIntToPtr`. However, since you say the previous value (`loc[n]`) was created via an `alloca` then it's already a pointer, and you don't need to perform any conversion: just do `builder->CreateLoad(loc[n])`.

By the way, the proper way to cast a Value to a Constant in LLVM is not via a c-style cast but via [`cast<>`](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates), like so: `cast<Constant>(loc[n])`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact my loc[n] is a Constant. My array loc is just typed as Value* but in my case I'm sure that loc[n] here is a Constant* so getIntToPtr should work for me ?

Comment: @user2390982 I assumed `loc` doesn't contain constants because you wrote that you placed a value there which you created with an `alloca` - and an `alloca` won't return a constant. In any case, if it's a constant there then `ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr` should indeed work. Also make sure your types match - an `alloca` returns a pointer, not a number, so I don't understand why you need `getIntToPtr` at all.

Comment: Ok sorry if I'm not clear. The problem is that I store in my `loc` array only constants I use in Create* functions. For example with `CreateAlloca(type,myConst)`, `loc` contains `myConst`, not returned value. That's why I have to use `getIntToPtr` for the `CreateLoad` instruction (am I right ?) And it's not working with code in original post.

Comment: @user2390982 could you better explain what are you trying to do? If you want to allocate an i32 and then load the content there (which will be undefined since it was just allocated, by the way), you use `CreateAlloca`, then pass the result into `CreateLoad`. It sounds as if instead you're using a constant integer as the alloca array size, then converting the integer to a pointer - that is certainly not what you intended.

Comment: Ok, I follow this scenario : As soon as I create a Constant* I store it in my loc array. For example :

`Value *newLocale = Constant::getIntegerValue(t,i);
loc[n] = newLocale;
builder->CreateAlloca(t,loc[n]);`

After in execution, I would like to create a Load instruction using loc[n] previously added :

`builder->CreateLoad(loc[n]);`

And the problem here is that my `loc[n]` is of type `Int32Ty` and it's not an `Int32PtrTy`. Am I forced to store the returned value of CreateAlloca ? Or could I get an Int32PtrTy from my current loc[n] ? (Something like builder->GetInt32PtrTy(loc[n]) ?)

Comment: @user2390982 what you just described is generally equivalent to this C code: `#define N <some number>` followed by `int[N] x; y = *((int*)N)`. You are treating a constant integer used as the array size as if it was an address and trying to load the data there - it's nonsensical. So yes, you have to use the values **returned** from `CreateAlloca` if you want to actually load or store using the allocated memory.